# Sed command to add a character when pattern is matched?

Tags: sed

I have the contents of file like:

```
data {
    x = "name",
    y = "job"
    z = "role"
  }
```

I want to add = in front of the curly bracket when it is missing, otherwise ignore it

Output should be :

```
data = {
    x = "name",
    y = "job"
    z = "role"
  }
```

I tried this but doesn't work.
`sed -r -ie 's|data \{ | data \= \{|g' abc.txt`

Can anybody please tell what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `sed -e 's/data[[:space:]]*{/data = {/'`

Comment: `{` matches a literal `{`, but `\{` is a regex brace.

Comment: @WilliamPursell No, because of `-r`, `{` is special and `\{` literal.

Comment: @WilliamPursell - Yeah, without `\{` it just gives "Unmatched \{"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -r -i 's|(data)[[:space:]]*(\{)|\1 = \2|g' abc.txt
sed -i 's|data[[:space:]]*\{|data = {|g' abc.txt
```

*Details*:

- `-r` (or `-E`) option enables POSIX ERE regex syntax
- `(data)[[:space:]]*(\{)` - matches and captures `data` into Group 1, `[[:space:]]*` matches any zero or more whitespaces, `(\{)` captures into Group 2 a `{` char
- `\1 = \2` - replaces with Group 1 value, space, `=`, space and Group 2 value.

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/1OiDmD).

**NOTE**: If you need to make sure the pattern matches the whole line add anchors, `^` and `$`:

```sh
's|^(data)[[:space:]]*(\{)$|\1 = \2|g'
```

In a GNU sed, you may use a shorter form for `[[:spaces:]]*`, `\s*`:

```sh
's|^(data)\s*(\{)$|\1 = \2|'
```

If there can be leading/trailing whitespace and you need to keep it use:

```sh
's|^(\s*data)\s*(\{\s*)$|\1 = \2|'
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed '/=/!s/data /&= /' abc.txt`

On lines not having an equal sign, replace data+space with data+space+equal+space.

Comment: Most people aim to be positive, for them perhaps:  `sed '/^data {/s/ / = /' file`